# AWS Image upload to Ec2 using java application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jakarta-ee, amazon-ec2

I have a problem with my java application runs on AWS EC2. The issue is, i can't upload image to AWS EC2. I am doing it first time, and don't know whether it is correct method or not, I just coded it like normal image upload in a local server.Some one please help me to fix this problem or if it is not the correct way, please suggest me the correct one.

## code

```
public String saveBannerInWebNotification(@RequestParam(value = "webBannerImg") MultipartFile webImg1) throws IOException
{
String img1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String filepath = "/datadisk/Images/banner/";
File file = new File(filepath + img1 + ".jpg");
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, webImg1.getBytes());
}
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with EC2. Did you test if your code runs on your local machine first? You have a method that needs to return a String, but there is no `return` statement.

Comment: Problem is solved, the folder which i tried to save was write protected.Any way thanks for the response.